# Export Flash Animation to ActionScript

Tags: flash, animation

I would like to make an animation using some tool (like e.g. Flash CS) and then export it for ActionScript.
I thought this could be done in Flash CS but I just tried it by making an animation, converting it to a symbol and then selecting "Export for ActionScript".
The problem: in the project folder there are no ActionScript classes generated.

Am I doing it wrong or do I have to use a different tool to do the animation?

Many many thanks for your help,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a movieclip to export for actionscript won't generate any classes for you (at least not that you can see). What it will do is allow you to reference that clip from code. The link below should get you headed in the right direction. Good luck!

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/external_files_as3/